# Rock Climbing in Peru: Should I bring my stuff?

Tags: rental, gear, peru, climbing

My girlfriend and I are travelling to Peru for a month and we'd like to do some rock climbing there, as it looks marvellously great. Although I have all the required stuff at home, I'm wondering if it's worth it to bring all for an entire month in which we also plan to do some long treks.

My question is: it is easy to rent a rope, harness and quick draws in Peru? Is it very expensive or is it possible to find a local community willing to share the stuff? Is it simpler to just bring the stuff?

Comment: I've traveled to Peru, but have no experience with climbing or its equipment. A brief Google search, however, yielded this: https://huascaran-peru.com/equipmet-rental-huaraz.php, and this: https://www.ericadventures.com/cusco-peru-rentals/camping-equipment-rental.html, and https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/americas-south-america/peru/rock-climbing-peru (the last is old, but the links may still be useful).

Comment: Might be best asking this on https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ or a rock climbing forum e.g. https://www.ukclimbing.com/forums/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've rock-climbed in Peru (Huaraz , Cusco, and Arequipa) and I've brought my own climbing shoes and harness (because they are quite light and also I cannot climb without my own shoes... maybe I'm a weirdo).

As for the rest, you can definitely rent it (you don't want to carry your rope and quick draws, it's just too heavy for your long hikes). I don't remember the price but it wasn't crazy expensive so that should be good!